# Android - Prevent chunking data written to OutputStream

Tags: java, android, sockets

### Problem

I'm developing a remote app to control software on remote machine through sockets.
Between my app and the softwares there is a sort of router/reverse proxy (software) to pass my commands to the desired software.

Unfortunately, for now, this router doesn't support chunked requests, ie all the command must be received in the same TCP packet else it interprets it as two separates ones.

On some devices all goes well. But some others the command is separated in two separates packets and doesn't be interpreted correctly by the router.

I want to prevent request chunking. Is this possible (Android side)?

### Technical details

#### Java code

In my app I'm using a `Socket` and a `DataOutputStream` to send commands, like this:

```
socket = new Socket(ip, port);
out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

The protocole to communicate with the router is a little bit weird but I need to send an HTTP header first (for a sort of authentication) waiting for an `OK` from server and then send my commands (without header this time)
I'm doing this like this:

```
# Sending header
out.writeBytes("SOURCE content HTTP/1.0\n" +
                "Content-type: type\n" +
                "Authorization: Basic\n" +
                "Nom: rouge\n\n");
# Getting server answer
String answer;
int charsRead;
char[] buffer = new char[256];
charsRead = in.read(buffer);
answer = new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);

# ... A little bit of computation of the answer to know if it's OK

# Sending my command to server
out.writeBytes("0 rouge violet getNext 1");

# Same as above to get and compute response
```

#### Devices used to test

- "Chunking" device : LG Nexus 5X - Android 7.1.2 - API 25
- "Non chunking" device : Kesa TM708 ($60 cheap tablet) - Android 5.1.1 - API 22
  It's exactly the same code on this two devices

#### Wireshark captures

Here the two requests sent:
[image: Wireshark captures]

- [Here the chunked capture file (pcap)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1PiuRzblqOEN0RMWFVBNzZaMGc/view?usp=sharing)
- [Here the not chunked capture file (pcap)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1PiuRzblqOETXRuVUUweXV6aU0/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you :)